# How is it possible to extract sub-strings using keywords and index?

Tags: python, string, data-manipulation

I'm trying to get certain sub-string following a keyword from a data string. 
These colleceted sub-strings are then joined together.

Is there a simpler approach than multiple for-loops-iterations, without using regular expressions?

I've tried to split the data string (-> list of words) and then iterate over it to temporarily save the index (in the list of words) where a keyword appeared.

Using these indexes, I can tell that the sub-string of keyword A is between the index of keyword A and keyword B. So I join these strings from the list.

This approach seems quite overcomplicated.

```py
data_string = "safpifucr keywordA: ejeca pfiktecr 3697406324 keywordB: 2505098781 epef ahemahkuj  keywordC: ezivwut 2564556750 inanrune"
keywords = ['keywordA:', 'keywordB:', 'keywordC:']
split_string = data_string.split()
keyword_index = []
# Getting the indexes of keywords
for index, word in enumerate(split_string, start=0):
    if word in keywords:
        keyword_index.append((word, index))


def getSubString(split_string, key_index, next_key_index):
    subString = []
    for index, sub in enumerate(split_string, start=0):
        if index > key_index and index < next_key_index:
            subString.append(sub)
    return subString
# Get SubString after Keyword A
subA = getSubString(split_string, keyword_index[0][1], keyword_index[1][1])
print(' '.join(subA)) # ejeca pfiktecr 3697406324

# Get SubString after Keyword A
subB = getSubString(split_string, keyword_index[1][1], keyword_index[2][1])
print(' '.join(subB)) # 2505098781 epef ahemahkuj

# Get SubString after Keyword A
subC = getSubString(split_string, keyword_index[2][1], len(split_string))
print(' '.join(subC)) # ezivwut 2564556750 inanrune
```

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to achieve the above result without having to iterate over the split_string multiple times. (n*keywords)

### Update

I require this for looking through banking records that have all the *Transaction Info* in one continous String. The various relevant informations are all behind keywords followed by a colon.
For various reasons I will not share the exact String but I've rebuilt some samples that are identical in structure just with fictional content.

```py
# Approach 2 of blhsing with RANDOM-DATA
keywords = set(['Empfänger:', 'Verwendungszweck:', 'Zahlungsempfänger:', 'Auftraggeberinformation:', 'Zahlungsreferenz:'])
mapping = {}
keyword = None
data_list = (
    'ONLINE BANKING VOM 1.10 UM 20:18  Empfänger:  Henrietta Mullins  Verwendungszweck:  bestellung 57E639 2019-06-10 terriblesuccess.SG',
    'SEPA Lastschrift  Zahlungsempfänger:  planetwötrap-AG  Verwendungszweck:  planetwötrap-AG-AG 460/487835-389 Ina Gill  Auftraggeberinformation:  3740930917-909/387187-3',
    'SEPA Lastschrift  Zahlungsempfänger:  AMAZON PAYMENTS EUROPE S.C.A.  Verwendungszweck:  409-7235170-354760 AMZN Mktp FI 3882385979  Auftraggeberinformation:  6V0RRQCT6GAACLH8',
    'POS 50,0648 FK K2 5.22 11:17 these cutting 5359')
for data_string in data_list:
    for word in data_string.split():
        if word in keywords:
            keyword = word
            print('if word in keywords: ', word)
        elif keyword in mapping:
            mapping[keyword] += ' ' + word
            print('elif keyword in mapping: ', word)
        elif keyword:
            mapping[keyword] = word
            print('elif keyword: ', word)
print(mapping)
```

This outputs

`{'Empfänger:': 'Henrietta Mullins', 'Verwendungszweck:': 'bestellung 57E639 2019-06-10 terriblesuccess.SG SEPA Lastschrift planetwötrap-AG-AG 460/487835-389 Ina Gill 409-7235170-354760 AMZN Mktp FI 3882385979', 'Zahlungsempfänger:': 'planetwötrap-AG AMAZON PAYMENTS EUROPE S.C.A.', 'Auftraggeberinformation:': '3740930917-909/387187-3 SEPA Lastschrift 6V0RRQCT6GAACLH8 POS 50,0648 FK K2 5.22 11:17 these cutting 5359'}`

Comment: What's wrong with using regular expressions? It's the best approach for the given problem.

Comment: How would you use the keyword list with the regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with an alternation pattern built from joining the keyword list to construct a dict that maps keywords to their values:

```
import re
dict(re.findall(r'\b({0})\s+(.*?)\s*\b(?={0}|$)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords))), data_string))
```

This returns:

```
{'keywordA:': 'ejeca pfiktecr 3697406324',
 'keywordB:': '2505098781 epef ahemahkuj',
 'keywordC:': 'ezivwut 2564556750 inanrune'}
```

With this dict it then becomes trivial to output the value of each given keyword.

Comment: Yes, it's more simple in terms of 'takes just one line'. I personally don't like it due to my inexperience in RE and also because it's very unreadable. Nevertheless, it's a viable approach I should consider, I'll look into it later.

Comment: It's also more efficient because it only scans the string once. Also, it's only unreadable if you don't know RE, which I highly recommend that you become familiar with.

Comment: After seeing how short the implementation became I can only agree.

Comment: I don't understand the part `re.escape`, because re.escape is a function and it's missing parantheses and parameters here. So, could you elaborate that for me?

Comment: Nevermind! It's inside of the map function! Ok, I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that also scans the string only once is to iterate through the words in the data string, save the keyword if a keyword is found (convert `keywords` to a set first for more efficient lookups), or if the word is not a keyword, assign and concatenate the word to a dict value of a mapping dict under the current keyword:

```
keywords = set(keywords)
mapping = {}
keyword = None
for word in data_string.split():
    if word in keywords:
        keyword = word
    elif keyword in mapping:
        mapping[keyword] += ' ' + word
    elif keyword:
        mapping[keyword] = word
```

`mapping` becomes:

```
{'keywordA:': 'ejeca pfiktecr 3697406324',
 'keywordB:': '2505098781 epef ahemahkuj',
 'keywordC:': 'ezivwut 2564556750 inanrune'}
```

Comment: I do prefer that approach.

Comment: It turns out that this specific approach does not work for my specific data_strings. Your regular expression example does however. Which means I was forced to look into it and indeed, it starts to become a bit more readable.

Comment: I see. Can you update your question with a sample of the actual `data_strings` that doesn't work with this solution? It should be quite easily fixable once the particulars about your actual `data_strings` are identified.

Comment: I updated the question, but  I should mention that I've definitly switched to your regular expression answer because it makes it quite more understandable (if RE is known, still working on that ^^) and efficient. The problem with this answer is that it doesn't stop adding to the mapping even if it's already the next item in the list. (which is problematic because they shouldn't get mixed up at all)